# Use openpyxl to verify the structure of a spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am working on a project that requires me to read a spreadsheet provided by the user and I need to build a system to check that the contents of the spreadsheet are valid. Specifically I want to validate that each column contains a specific datatype.

I know that this could be done by iterating over every cell in the spreadsheet, but I was hoping there is a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just manually looking at each cell. I have to read them all into my data structures before I can process anything anyways so it actually made sense to check then.

Answer (score 2):

In openpyxl you'll have to go cell by cell.

You could use Excel's builtin Data Validation or Conditional Formatting, which openpyxl supports, for this. Let Excel do the work and talk to it using xlwings.